# How much memory/cpu is mds_stores consuming for you?

Tags: spotlight

I'm trying to figure out if the spotlight process "mds_stores" is consuming more resources than it should be. I've turned spotlight on and off and reindexed everything but it's still regularly using between 40 and 80% of the CPU on my lightly loaded system and chewing through insane amounts of memory even after a reboot. Right now, the real memory and private memory it's consuming is over 32 GB on a 64 GB machine. This doesn't seem normal to me.

As far as I can tell, Spotlight finished indexing my drive over a day ago yet mds_stores is still consuming a bunch of resources.

I've told Spotlight to ignore my external drive and the caches. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Something is definitely wrong on your end. FWIW My system was rebooted 12 hours ago and at the moment I have one occurrence in **Activity Monitor**: `mds_stores 0.0 22.19 4 0 0.0 0.00 295 root 153.9 MB 81.3 MB 44.1 MB 42.5 MB 0 bytes 0 bytes  0 bytes 0 bytes 0 0 (null) - No No No No Yes Yes 0 bytes 0 bytes (null)`

Comment: OK, thanks for the feedback. I just discovered that when I tell spotlight to ignore the "Macintosh HD" volume, everything went back to normal. This isn't a proper fix, obviously, but at least it tells me the process itself isn't buggy. Theres's something somewhere on the drive that's making it go crazy.

Comment: Interestingly, after adding "Macintosh HD" back to spotlight search (by removing it from the "Privacy" pane in Spotlight system preference), the amount of resources getting consumed are remaining normal.

Comment: Hopefully it stays that way.

Comment: I just removed a bunch of folders from the Spotlight Privacy settings and memory is now hovering only around 1 GB but CPU usage has shot back up to between 50% and 200%. But that's because Spotlight is now reindexing those folders. I'll have to wait until indexing finishes and reboot to know for sure. I'll report back what I find. This seems to be a prettty common problem.

Comment: RE: "This seems to be a pretty common problem." --  Yes it does appear to be. Any time I've had an issue with it a reboot has rectified the issue.

Comment: How exactly are you measuring the memory of mds_stores? Could you edit in the question a specific command? I will do the same on my Mac as well so we can compare. I almost all the cases - when spotlight is out of control, it's the data on your disk or a broken spotlight importer due to a third party app, but let's take the first step before we go down the `mddiagnose` path...

Comment: I'm just looking at the activity monitor, not running a command. Both the real memory and the private memory were well over 32 GB and growing immediately after a reboot. Right now, with spotlight in the middle reindexing everything, memory is now a more reasonable 2.2 GB.

Comment: It should work itself out - expecially if you can back up some files to an external drive and disconnect it. Also - is your memory pressure in green / yellow / red normally? (I believe you have an issue, but that spotlight is an innocent bystander and not the cause in most cases)

Comment: The memory pressure isn't an issue at first. When I had 40 GB of memory, I would start seeing issues pretty frequently. Then I upgraded to 64 GB. But after a while, I had memory pressure issues too, it just took longer to get there. I initially thought it was memory leaks in my audio and streaming software that I recently started using but have since isolated it to mds_stores.

Comment: mds_stores "Real memory" usage is now peaking at around 16 GB and private memory is now over 7 GB while spotlight reindexes. These numbers keep climbing. Though this is an improvement over the 32 GB of used memory I was getting before, it's getting a little worrying.

Comment: I'm getting this problem non stop on my Catalina MBP. Except mds_stores is using up to 62 GB out of just 8 GB actually installed in the Mac. Not good.

Answer (score 0):

After reindexing everything again and waiting a full 48 hours, CPU usage has finally dropped down to normal levels, using just around .1% of CPU for mds_stores and mds. Memory is still pretty high at around 18 GB of memory. While indexing, this number went up to as high as 44 GB on a 64 GB machine.

And it looks to me like mds_stores will continue to use a lot of resources even after the drives are indexed by Spotlight. Perhaps it is making the search index more efficient. At any rate, it took many, may hours to for this to happen before CPU usage dropped from roughly 50% to .1%. It could be a function of me having a 4 TB drive. I'm not sure.

But as far as I can tell, it seems to be working smoothly now.

Comment: Try rebooting and check the memory usage afterwards - the 18 GB figure could just be because of (unintended) memory leaks.

Answer (score -2):

The system is designed to store data from the filesystem in memory so unless you need RAM for other things this is a benefit, intended and normal.

Below is a snapshot of a machine where I'm processing about 35 TB of data - rsync from several direct attached drives to other direct attached drives. About 900,000 files on each of the 5 connected drives, photos syncing, etc...

[image: spotlight process memory usage on macOS Big Sur]

I would look at your memory pressure graph in Activity Monitor and see what you see in terms of trends instead of one snapshot. Just because memory is allocated now, it can be de-allocated and freed in an instant if needed. Virtual memory is not like a physical warehouse where you have to move things out and it’s a problem to be 98% full. In fact, it’s the opposite, you are spending energy to keep RAM active always, so the system might as well use it all rather than waste it.

For context - here is the entire system memory contents sorted by the processes that allocate more RAM than others.

[image: memory usage of all processes on macOS Big Sur]

This Mac has been running for a month and mds_stores has used 9 minutes and 15 seconds of CPU time in that month.

[image: CPU usage of mds_stores and spotlight on macOS Big Sur]

---

In response to the comment that mds_stores does not grow and shrink, I run this command to check on it when I have a suspect "spotlight" issue:

```
% sudo vmmap -resident -w mds_stores|grep footprint
Physical footprint:         102.0M
Physical footprint (peak):  352.4M
```

Comment: This is not correct. When memory is shown as real and private memory allocated by mds_stores, it is not data that is cached from the file system, and it will definitely not be de-allocated and freed in an instant if needed.

Comment: That's not been my experience @jksoegaard lately on Mojave and newer. As you can see - I push a lot of files on 8 GB RAM - if there were a problem with the OS - I would likely see it before someone that buys more RAM, don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, my understanding is that the real memory is what matters. I don't think 32 GB for something basically searching for files would be considered normal. Also, the CPU usage at 50% after everything had been indexed tells me something is wrong. And the memory getting freed up after removing the "Maciontosh HD" from Spotlight would also seem to indicate that spotlight is stuck on some file somwhere on the drive.

Comment: Oh, and also, I have been having problems with memory usage for a while. I really started noticing it when I started live streaming even with 40 GB or RAM. I upped it to 64 GB, which is insane, and still run into problems, though less frequently. So the mac is not managing the memory used by mds_stores at all. It's just chewing up memory and resources and screwing up my ability to use the machine.

Comment: so - that would be an excellent case to run `sysdiagnose` if you feel the system needs an engineering review or `mddiagnose` if you think it's just the spotlight subsystem that's cranky. You are correct - if you have a runaway memory usage issue - no amount of memory will solve it. At best if you have a slow issue, it delays the examination and eventual stall / crash.

Comment: OK, but not sure I would know what I was looking at. I'll read up on these commands though. Thanks.

Comment: I'd start with the CPU use for a day and the `sudo vmmap -resident -w mds_stores|grep footprint` to start. There's so, so, so much detail in the diagnosis scripts. It's taken me far too long to learn what is meaningful and what to ignore or pay Apple to fix when I get too deep in the weeds...

Comment: @bmike Sorry, but this is not a matter of experience. What I describe is fact. If the operating system worked as you described it, programs would crash left and right. You're the one bringing up "a problem with the OS" - I haven't written anything like that. The amount of RAM in the machine does not change how this mechanism works.

Comment: I don't understand your facts @jksoegaard - maybe we don't agree on terminology or you think I'm saying something I am not? the process grows and shrinks and the data it processes is cached from the filesystem. Where else would spotlight get data to store in memory?

Comment: @bmike As written in the question, he's experiencing mds_stores using 32 GB of real and private memory. You answer that this is a benefit as the system is designed to store data from the filesystem in memory. But this argument is flawed - data cached from the file system does NOT show up as real and private memory allocated by the mds_stores process. That's not how that works.

Comment: @bmike  You also write that this is the "system using it all rather than wasting it" and that this will simply be freed in an instant, if needed for other things. That's also not the case. As the memory is allocated as real and private memory for the mds_stores process, the operating system cannot simply free up that memory at will whenever it is needed for other things. The operating system does not tell mds_stores that this memory is now needed for other stuff, nor does it automatically free that memory.

Comment: @bmike You are stating some things here in the comments that are true, but they're misapplied here. Yes, the mds_stores process does "grow and shrink" over time (as do any other process), but that doesn't mean that it is part of a caching system nor that it will be freed when it is needed. The "growing and shrinking" is controlled entirely by mds_stores, not the operating system.

Comment: @bmike The finals part of your comment where you state that the memory taken up by mds_stores is used for data "cached from the file system" - and "where else would spotlight get data to store in memory" are unfounded. It is simply not so that this data allocation serves as a "file system cache", nor that the data stored in memory must come from the file system. For all we know, this could very well be a bug in mds_stores, where some small, but unexpected, piece of data in the file systems, makes mds_stores  uses tonnes of memory unnecessarily.

Comment: Aah, you’re reading my explanation of the overall system and applying it to one process. My point to the OP is to not fixate on one process and instead the larger picture.

Comment: How does that make sense? - If I have a problem with a bug in Microsoft Word where it takes up half of my memory when loading a one page letter - should I just say "never mind, the rest of my programs are working fine - let's not focus on this one bad program"? - Ofcourse not, we should work towards getting that bug fixed or finding a work-around. Not everyone has the good fortune that they can just sign off  lots of system resources for buggy programs, and still have a speedy computer doing all the stuff they want it to do.